# Timer to fire an event WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, timer

I have a project here and it has set by default that the actions occur by MouseEnter event. I mean, opening a Window, closing, returning, whatever, happens only by the MouseEnter event.

I was requested to make the event fire only after 3 seconds. That means that the user will place the mouse on the control and only after 3 seconds the event must happen for all the controls in the window.

So, I thought about a global timer or something alike, that will return false untill the timer reaches 3... I think that's the way...

Geez, does anybody knows how can I make such thing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you you just sleep for 3 seconds in the MouseEnter event?

Comment: Sleeping for 3 seconds in the MouseEnter event will lock the UI for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a class that will expose a `DelayedExecute` method that receives an action to execute and creates timers as needed for the delayed execution. It would look something like this:

```
public static class DelayedExecutionService
{
    // We keep a static list of timers because if we only declare the timers
    // in the scope of the method, they might be garbage collected prematurely.
    private static IList<DispatcherTimer> timers = new List<DispatcherTimer>();

    public static void DelayedExecute(Action action, int delay = 3)
    {
        var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

        // Add the timer to the list to avoid it being garbage collected
        // after we exit the scope of the method.
        timers.Add(dispatcherTimer);

        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Stop the timer so it won't keep executing every X seconds
            // and also avoid keeping the handler in memory.
            dispatcherTimer.Tick -= handler;
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();

            // The timer is no longer used and shouldn't be kept in memory.
            timers.Remove(dispatcherTimer);

            // Perform the action.
            action();
        };

        dispatcherTimer.Tick += handler;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
DelayedExecutionService.DelayedExecute(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello!"));
```

or

```
DelayedExecutionService.DelayedExecute(() => 
{
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
});
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome solution Sir!! It worked perfectly!! I'm just going to think about a visual feedback, like a growing circle arround the cursor, or something alike!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArmandoFreire Glad to hear. Note that I modified the code to avoid possible memory leak.

Comment: Sure @AdiLester, I just updated mine as well! The code saved a bunch of time here!! Really thanks!

Comment: Hey @Adi , how do i add more than one method on that event? I mean, i'm trying to run two methods, (e.g. calling two message boxes) but it's not working. Do I have to call that function twice?

Comment: @ArmandoFreire The delegate you pass can execute several statements. I've updated my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in XAML template? I am trying to do the animation when button is clicked but i do not want CLick event to be fired before the animation is complete.

Comment: @StefanVasiljevic In that case you could register to the storyboard's `Completed` event and execute your logic there.

Comment: @StefanVasiljevic Yes. Google the `Completed` event - I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: could please help me, I am trying to implement this code to delay a text change event from firing, and I am kind of lost...

Comment: I want to delay the even from firing every time it is called during one during one run for 3 seconds.

Comment: @LittleProgrammer You're probably looking for delayed binding: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/21/wpf-4-5-part-4-the-new-bindings-delay-property/

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a simpler solution:

```
public static void DelayedExecute(Action action, int delay = 3000)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
        action();
    }
}
```

Then use it just like in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12342208/677014)

Comment: It is indeed simpler, but I think `Sleep` should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @AdiLester can you please comment on why?

Comment: This article specifies several reasons: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx