# Add Delay To Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, delay

I am making a game, and I have a timer for an Image to appear. In a different method I am saying to delete those images. Using the same dispatcherTimer, but delayed several seconds. Any help?

Timer:

```
// Timer for Mole to Appear \\
private void randomMoleTimer()
{
    DispatcherTimer randomMole = new DispatcherTimer();
    randomMole.Tick += new EventHandler(randomMole_Tick);
    randomMole.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    randomMole.Start();
}
```

I need to add the delay here:

```
private void MoleImage_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    molePopup = MoleImage();
    grid_Main.Children.Remove(molePopup);
}
```

Comment: This may be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342116/timer-to-fire-an-event-wpf

Answer (score -1):

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

Will make your app pause for 5 seconds

This may help what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: This will also hang OPs UI for 5 seconds.

Comment: @spender Yeah, thats not going to work. Do you have any ideas?