# Delay timer for KeyDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `Textbox` that has a `KeyDown` event. This Event is bound with an event handler in the ViewModel. Below is the sample code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=TextBoxKeyDownEvent}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<TextBox.InputBindings>
```

It is true that as soon as the user starts writing in the texbox, the backend event handler in ViewModel is called. But I don't want to call the event handler for each KeyDown operation. I want to call the event handler when the user starts typing in the textbox and stops for at least N milliseconds. That means I need to set a delay timer for the event. Can anyone please guide me how I can achieve that in MVVM?

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the [`BindingBase.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Delay=500, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This will modify the `TextBoxText` property in your viewmodel only 500 milliseconds after it has been changed by the user. Then, in your setter you can call any code you'd like to execute.

```
private string textBoxText;
public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return textBoxText; }
    set
    {
        // Setter will be called only 500 milliseconds after the user has entered text.
        if (textBoxText != value)
        {
            textBoxText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxText");

            // Handle text change.
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the delay to happen also when the property is changed in the code, you could use something similar to the solution mentioned here: [Timer to fire an event WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12342116/389966)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I can't use it in TextProperty Change event. Because the text can be changed by the program internally. So  here the event handler will work only when the text change will happen by writing on it. That's why i need to work with the keydown event.

Comment: I think I have failed to make you understand the purpose. I have a TextBox and in that TextBox for every Keypress there is a command binding. That Binded method call the view and the view fetch data from the database.  But I don't want that for each and every key press the binded method will be called. I want that if the user stop typing for a certain amount of time(like 500 ms), only then the binded method will be called.

Comment: Note: This property is new to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Set a timer and a Time out Event

```
    private System.Timers.Timer keypressTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    keypressTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```

Inside the timeout event do your task -

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        keypressTimer.Stop();
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {

            //CALL YOUR EVENT HERE

        });

    }
```

Each time the key will be press - you need to reset the timer in the following way.

```
    if (delayTime > 0)
            {
                keypressTimer.Interval = delayTime;
                keypressTimer.Start();
            }
```